# Downvoted a bad answer and got a -1 myself?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

I downvoted a bad answer here:

[can I hide certain HTML things using purely CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335019/can-i-hide-certain-html-things-using-purely-css/31335083#31335083)

Which already has 7 downvotes, and I myself got a -1 in my notification. Why?

Comment: That's an answer, not a question.

Answer (score 5):

Working as documented.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Quote:

"You lose reputation when:

- among other points...
- you vote down an answer: −1"

If the question gets deleted, you get the point back.

Comment: Oh, so downvoting the question is ok, but answer is not. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Downvoting an answer is more than okay.

Comment: @dingo Please downvote bad answers! It is totally ok. The 1 rep point is just a small investment to prevent bad behaviour (like people downvoting all competing answers).

Comment: I also flagged the answer for low quality. I just saw that it was really bad, and decided to slap a -1 on it (didn't feel like commenting since it already had some comments).

Comment: Don't worry about it. It will most likely be deleted and you'll get your 1 rep back

Comment: Probably the general misconception here is that a loss of reputation is a sign that you did something bad. Not at all. You can also "lose" reputation when an upvote on a question or answer you wrote gets reversed for whatever reason. Its only a statistic: your rep went down. It does not say: you did something bad, slap on the wrist.